# How to select elements of an array from a specific axis in Python

Tags: numpy

I am working with multidimensional arrays with dynamical axes. Now I want to select elements of the array along a specific axis.
For example, if I have a 3-dimensional array, I want to pick the elements like this

```
b = a[:, :, 1]
```

Now my problem is that after one iteration of code the same array becomes 4 dimensional. And again I want to pick the elements like this

```
b = a[:,:,1,:]
```

Thus I am looking for a general solution to pick all elements from the 3rd axis of the array. This is very simple if I had to choose `a[1]` and I could get `a[1,:,:,:]`, but I am not aware how to chose for other axes.

Edit:
Also, I would be interested in a solution where the interested axis also changes for example with the same code and next iteration I would like to get

```
b = a[:,:,:,1]
```

Comment: You don't have to include the trailing colon.  But take a look at `np.take`.

Comment: That solves my problem actually! but I added another case in my question, can you please help also

Comment: thanks. np.take solved my problem!

Comment: Not entirely sure why you need to iterate over in the array in the first place (as opposed to vectorizing). But for your second case the slices can be encapsulated by doing ```b = a[(slice(None), slice(None), slice(None), 1)]``` (the selected index can now be saved as a variable).

Comment: Another thing that some `numpy` functions do is use  `transpose` (or `swapaxes`) to move a desired dimension to the start or end, making it easier to operate with a known configuration.  Reshaping to condense several dimensions down to 1 may also be handy.